# How to reset variable in For .. Do loop?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, directory

How do I reset the retained variable to 0 in a do loop? I would like to reset is idx.

idx represent the number of the subfolder being searched.

For example there are total 100 subfolders, so idx max=100. when macro finds the match folder, eg. 50. it retains the idx=50. So for the new search, idx would not go from the beginning, instead, it continues the new search from 51, 52, 53...100. So if the matched subfolder idx is 20, since the macro didn't go through 0-50, it will treat it as not found and exit the loop.

Where I could reset this variable?

```vb
    Dim idx As Integer
    For idx = 0 To UBound(Array_SubFolders)
        Dim fileName As String
        fileName = Dir(Array_SubFolders(idx) & "/*.xlsb")
        On Error Resume Next
        Do While fileName <> ""
            FullPathFileName = Array_SubFolders(idx) & "\" & fileName
            If (Left(fileName, 12) = "Ass_Sheet_") Then
                Dim prodName As String
                prodName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Cells(MasterRow, 1).Value
                If (InStr(fileName, prodName) > 0) Then
                    Call prc_Import_Values(fileName)
                    MasterRow = MasterRow + 1
                End If
            End If
            fileName = Dir()
        Loop

    Next

    MsgBox "--- finished ---"
```

Comment: 1) You appear to be missing some code, `next idx` (and maybe other stuff) is missing 2) By "rest" do you mean "reset"? 3) Is `prc_Import_Values` a recursive function and is the above the code for it?

Comment: is this a function? where does `Array_SubFolders`comes from?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad you are right, 1) "rest" = reset.  @)prc_Import_Values is another function to import the value when after the macro find the correct folder, and file. That part works quite well, I didnt put the code here.  the only problem here is to reset the idx, so when the new search begin , it will search from the first subfolder, where the array store all the subfound detected.

Comment: @mdelapena array_Subfolders is the other function to store all the subfolders , and the codes i posted is for the one to find the match folder.

Comment: Sidenote - I think you should be using a backward slash for this `"/*.xlsb")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, I'd **strongly** suggest removing the `On Error Resume Next` as leaving it in will only lead to suffering and heartache when something breaks and you don't get any error message. If you're getting an error message with it removed, you should track down the source of the error and either fix that or handle it with appropriate guard clauses or error handling.

Second, I *think* you want to repeatedly search the entirety of  `Array_SubFolders` for a file with `prodName` in its name any of the files in each sub folder. If that's the case, I'd suggest something like this:

```
Dim index As Integer
index= 0
Do While index < UBound(Array_SubFolders) 
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = Dir(Array_SubFolders(index) & "\*.xlsb")
    Do While fileName <> ""
        FullPathFileName = Array_SubFolders(index) & "\" & fileName
        If (Left(fileName, 12) = "Ass_Sheet_") Then
            Dim prodName As String
            prodName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Cells(MasterRow, 1).Value
            If (InStr(fileName, prodName) > 0) Then
                Call prc_Import_Values(fileName)
                MasterRow = MasterRow + 1
                index = 0
            End If
        End If
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop
    index = index+ 1
Loop
```

Instead of using a `For...Next` loop and trying to reset the index (which is usually recommended against), this uses a `Do While...Loop` and resets the index when it finds a match on the `If (InStr(fileName, prodName) > 0) Then` line. If that's the wrong place, then you can move the `index = 0` to wherever the actual matching takes place.

Also, note that I changed `idx` to `index`. Vowels are cheap and I believe that not disemvoweling variables makes them more readable. Plus, with the VBIDE's auto-complete, typing `in<ctrl-space>` will probably get you the same result with the same number of keystrokes.

Comment: Thanks @FreeMan for your constructive advice. Before reading your comment, I change it to do while..loop as well. And then I tried to modified my codes according to your changes above. The index reset problem is solved, but the loop has no exit now.. E.g: I just want to search 2 product name, but after the 2 product name, the macro still keep importing the data (the file of the next index)

Comment: Glad you found that helpful. If you need an additional way of breaking out of the loop, you could do `index = UBount(Array_SubFolder) + 1` when you reach the "break out" condition, or you could change the `Do While index < UBound()` to `Do While index < UBound() and OtherCondition = True`

Comment: I am a little confused here.Maybe my question before just ask how to reset the index, then I didn't explain my scenario.  Actually, my index refers to the specific Subfolders retained by the Array. So the first target is to search for the subfolder I need from a list of product name , and the next loop to find the file that match my conditions. Before reading your advice, my idea was quite simple, to exit the loop when the product name list ends. I try to add this condition to my loop, not succeeded yet.

Comment: Finally, it is working. Thanks for your help Freeman.Very appreciated!